# Strange behavior of inputs during pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason, when switching to `Registration`, the 3rd input "inherits" the `value` from the previous state, that is, in theory, it should not have a `value`, but nevertheless an equal `Login` appears. How to fix?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Auth() {
    const [pagination, setPagination] = useState('log');

    function pag() {
        if (pagination === 'log') {
            return (
                <>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="email"
                        placeholder="E-mail"
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="password"
                        placeholder="Пароль"
                    />
                    <input
                        type="button"
                        className="done"
                        value="Войти"
                    />                   // From here is transmitted
                </>
            );
        }

        return (
            <>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="email"
                    placeholder="E-mail"
                />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="password"
                    placeholder="Пароль"
                />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="password password-repeat"
                    placeholder="Повторите пароль"
                />                                          // To here
                <input
                    type="button"
                    className="done"
                    value="Зарегестрироваться"
                />
            </>
        );
    }

    function changePag(ev) {
        if (ev.target.dataset.type === 'log') {
            setPagination('log');
        } else {
            setPagination('reg');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="auth_page">
            <div className="pagination">
                <input
                    type="button"
                    className="log"
                    data-type="log"
                    onClick={changePag}
                    value="Вход"
                />
                <input
                    type="button"
                    className="reg"
                    data-type="reg"
                    onClick={changePag}
                    value="Регистрация"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form">
                {pag()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Auth;
```

Comment: I think this may come from the fact that react is re-using the input DOM element and, if you are not using [controlled inputs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-js-uncontrolled-vs-controlled-inputs/) it might keep its old value. Try controlling your input values manually and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @QuinnFreedman, please give an example

Comment: The article I linked has an example with explanation